# How to run a rule in outlook using an external vbscript file ?

Tags: vbscript, outlook

i have a rule in my Outlook. I need an external `.vbs.` file to fire the rule. How can I do this ?

`set myOutlook = createobject("outlook.application")`

I tried to read documentation on Microsoft website, but could not find a `rule` object

Comment: Where did you look exactly? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864433(v=office.15).aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Rule object!

Rule.Execute Method (Outlook)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff864433(v=office.15).aspx